# Ping increase internet speed

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ping, cmd.exe

Can I use ping to increase internet speed?

```
ping [IPv4 of wifi] -n 100000
```

Is this increasing my internet speed?

Comment: There is nothing you can do as a customer of a service provider to decrease your ping and ping as NOTHING to do with how quickly you download a file because your speed depends on how many bytes your able to receive in a given amount of time.

Comment: @Ramhound Well... *latency* (which is what a lot of people talking about "ping" really mean) doesn't have *nothing* to do with it, since higher latency means longer time for a TCP ACK, which does have an impact on throughput if you have smaller buffers and higher latencies - the server simply won't send any new packets until enough of the previous ones are acknowledged as received (or they'll be resent). On the other hand, the `ping` utility itself? Yea, that's got nothing to do with it, apart from measuring latency - it won't *change* anything.

Comment: My point was more along the line of the fact if you have a huge pipe but the latency is bad it makes up for the fact it took awhile.

Answer (score 1):

No ping will not increase your speed.  PING only will tell you if the destination is reachable and how long it took to get there.

Comment: OK, youtube videos are unbelievable. But still, pinging increase my loading page speed a bit - anybody explain?

Comment: It actually doesn't update your question with the numbers

Comment: Placebo effect most likely

Comment: @Jamie, ping tells your computer to contact a system at that domain name (e.g. google.com) or IP address. It may find a shorter route than before when performing this, so that's why it may make pages "load faster."

Comment: OIC. If it really finds that, i think i am good luck enough lol

Answer (score 1):

Sending ping requests out will not increase your network speed.  Actually, it can cause your network speed to slow slightly, as all you are doing is generating unnecessary network traffic for you to compete with.  Standard ping requests have such a small packet size that the effect will be nearly unnoticeable, but it definitely WILL NOT increase your speed.

Basically, this is like someone convincing you that your call will go faster if you slightly press on the brakes.  It just doesn't work that way.